# More complicated uSubstitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I have absolutely no idea what to do here other than use uSubstitution.
$$\int{{1}\over{4x^2 + 9}}\mathrm dx$$

I also tried looking at the output of an [integral calculator](http://www.integral-calculator.com/) but to no avail.

I noticed they let $u = 2x/3$

The only way I can remotely get close to that is:

$$\sqrt{4x^2} = 2x$$
$$\sqrt{9} = 3$$

Even then using the given value of u , I can't seem to get to the answer. My only other help is that the paper this came out had five possible answers which all hinted that arctan was used somewhere.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By setting $x=\frac{3}{2}t$ you are left with an elementary integral.

Comment: It might help noting that the derivative of $\arctan{x}$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Answer (score 7):

rewrite the given integral in the form $$\frac{1}{9}\int \frac{dx}{\left(\frac{2}{3}x\right)^2+1}$$ and set $$t=\frac{2x}{3}$$